# How to exclusion join 2 NSArrays?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I've got 2 arrays of objects (as NSArray's) and I want to get an array of the objects in the first that aren't also in the 2nd.

Comment: should have mentioned this is for an iPhone app

Answer (score 3):

See `NSMutableArray`'s  `-removeObjectsInArray:` method.

Comment: Thanks, once I figured out how to create NSMutableArray's from NSArrays I got it working.  
  
`NSMutableArray* oldAnnotations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[mapView.annotations count]];  
[oldAnnotations addObjectsFromArray:mapView.annotations];`

Answer (score 1):

1) Inefficient solution. run over one array and call on each object containsObject if no do add the element otherwise take the next element

2) More efficient: sort both array and then step them side-by side. Keep a reference to the last added object and then compare the next components to this element. If none matches you can add a new "last" element.

3) Drop all the Elements in a HashTable then take the next elements of the next array and check  whether  you can find an "equal" object. At the end rebuild an Array from the HashTable

4) drop all the elements into an NSSet and after that rebuild an Array  from this NSSet

Comment: Go with number 4, it's easier.

Comment: @Friedrich Thanks, I think hashtable won't work on iPhone. How do I get exclusion join from NSSet?

Comment: I think if I convert them to NSMutableSet I can do intersectSet: to remove the objects from the other set

Comment: Well NSŚet should not add a duplicate to it so I was just thinking of enumerating the second array and just call addObject (or however it is named) for each element of the other array.